# Can not manually change the permalink of a post in the EDIT secion

Tags: permalinks

I have my site using a custom permalink structure, specifically category/post.

Recently I noticed, once in the actual edit page interface I was unable to use the "EDIT" feature for the permalinks (i.e. the ones that are displayed under the post title.)

I logged in using a different browser and it worked the first time I hit edit, then after that it stopped again. I am wondering if this is a JavaScript issue? Maybe a plugin problem?

I can not edit the date option either on the top right either.

Anybody have this issue?

Comment: try deactivating your themes and see if you get it running if so then you know its one of your plugins

Comment: nice idea, I hate to loose my widget structure :(

Comment: well did you get anything from that?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use the same permalink for different pages, but Wordpress won't give you a error message detailing this when editing a permalink. It just silently fails.

This could be the case here? Confusing; pages in 'Trash' still count...

Comment: My suggestion as the most-likely culprit was going to be that you have a Page with an identical slug, in the trash - but Wietse Venema beat me to the punch. :)